# netty the proper location to put the encoder

Tags: netty

The Netty javadoc shows the typical usage of encoder as follows.

Decoder --> Encoder --> (messageReceived) Handler (Write).

Now, what I want to do it to encode the message that is written (well, I mean the message processed with write method in the handler). So, I guess the proper way to locate the decoder is as follows..

Decoder --> (messageReceived) Handler (Write) --> Eecoder

Since the Decoder returns Object, I wonder it can be a proper message..
Could you please, advise what I should do if I want to encode the message after write method?

Your suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the javadoc here: http://netty.io/4.0/api/

Where it talks about Upstream and Downstream, in Netty4 these are considered Inbound and Outbound. The docs reference both occasionally.

Particularly look at the example: (I've changed it slightly)

```
 ChannelPipeline p = ...;
 p.addLast("1", new InboundHandlerA());
 p.addLast("2", new InboundHandlerB());
 p.addLast("3", new OutboundHandlerA());
 p.addLast("4", new OutboundHandlerB());
 p.addLast("5", new HandlerX());
```

In this example, ChannelHandlers named Inbound* implement ChannelInboundHandler. ChannelHandlers named Outbound implement ChannelOutboundHandler.

HandlerX implements ChannelInboundHandler because it handles the incoming message event, and generates an outgoing message event by writing to the channel.

When there is an Inbound event (like Netty reading in data sent to the socket the channel is bound to) InboundHandler* are executed in order from top to bottom.

*InboundHandlerA -> InboundHandlerB -> HandlerX*

When there is an Outbound event (like your HandlerX writing to the channel), OutboundHander* are executed in order from **bottom to top**

*OutboundHandlerB -> OutboundHandlerA.*

As an extension, you can have a ChannelHandler which implements both Inbound and Outbound, and will be called twice in the execution of the pipeline.

So in your case you want something like

```
 ChannelPipeline p = ...;
 p.addLast("DECODER", new MyMessageDecoder());
 p.addLast("ENCODER", new MyMessageEncoder());
 p.addLast("HANDLER", new MyHandler());
```

where MyMessageDecoder and MyHandler implement ChannelInboundHandler, and MyMessageEncoder implements ChannelOutboundHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you put it like this:

Encoder1, Encoder2, Decoder1, Decoder2, other handler